# Unable to add PPA repository from terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, ppa

I am trying to install `ap-hotspot` on Ubuntu-14.04

When I enter the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

It gives me this message

> "Cannot add PPA: 'ppa"nilarimogard/webupd8'
>    Please check that the PPA name and format is correct"

How do I proceed?

Since I am using college proxy to access the Internet,
so I tried

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

but it didn't help. But I am able to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

so there is no problem with the internet connection.
I also tried reinstalling ca-cerficates by using the command

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

it also didn't solve the problem.
I also tried from Ubuntu Software Center, but there I am also unable to add a PPA repository.

please help me in resolving this problem...

Comment: Add the following lines manually to your software sources config: `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/unstable/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/unstable/ubuntu trusty main`  If you're using 14.10 change trusty to utopic

Comment: @eyoung100 Thank you, I tried adding above lines in **etc/apt/sources.list** but when i run `apt-get update', It gives error **"W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886"**          I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Visit the [PPA here](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8).  Click Technical Details, try adding it again, if the same error repeats ignore the error.

Comment: Thanks @eyoung100, Now,I am able to install **ap-hotspot** .

Comment: np.  Would you like me to add an answer?

Comment: Ya sure, It will be perfect..

Comment: Answer has been written.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you can't add the repository, you can always add them from a terminal using the command line.  Browse to the [list of the repositories at the WebUpd8 Website](http://www.webupd8.org/p/ubuntu-ppas-by-webupd8.html).  Copy down the address of the master repository, which is [Master Repository](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8).  You want to add this one because it contains all the others.

1. `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup`
2. `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
3. Visit [Master Repository](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8) in a Web Browser.
4. Find the Dropdown Arrow that reads:

   > Technical Details about this PPA
5. Click Your Ubuntu Version in the List Labeled **Choose Your Version**
6. Add the resulting output into the file in Step 2.
7. Save the File
8. `sudo apt-get update`.  This update command should now fetch the Private Keys of the new Repository.  If you receive the error as you stated in your comment, then this repository has no private key.  You may want to contact the PPA maintainer at that point who will either give you the key, or tell you to ignore the Warning.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue while installing Oracle JDK on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.So after few search, I found a solution that really worked. We just need to add software properties and then we can install Oracle JDK on our Linux machine. Follow below steps

```
Step-1 Open terminal Ctrl + Alt + T
Step-2 sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
Step-3 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
Step-4 sudo apt-get update
Step-5 sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

This package will run an installer for The **Oracle JDK 8**, which is the current stable release. You may also replace java8 in the package name with java7 or java9 to install different versions, although these releases are not recommended for development.

Verify that Java and the Java compiler have been properly installed:

```
Step-6 java -version or javac -version
```